# Pyparsing setParseAction doesn't convert string to int

Tags: python, pyparsing

I'm trying to parse some ancient industrial equipment data format using `pyparsing` and run into a behavior I don't understand.

The input string format is: `R<x0>,<y0>,<w>,<h>[,*<level>];`, where x0, y0, w, h are real numbers, level is integer in range of 1-8. The star marks the presence of the level token and the whole level construct can be omitted, in which case it is defaulted to `1`.

I want the parser to output a list of numbers like this `[x0, y0, w, h, level]` with the numbers being converted to appropriate data types.

The parser I wrote does almost exactly what I want with a single nuance:

```
from pyparsing import Word, nums, ZeroOrMore, Suppress, Literal, Optional, Combine, StringEnd, srange

rtext = 'R.0,.2,5.7,.2,*1;'
# rtext = 'R0.0,0.2,5.7,0.2;'

real = Combine(ZeroOrMore(Word(nums)) + Literal('.') + Word(nums)).setParseAction(lambda s, l, t: float(t[0]))
level = Word(srange('[1-8]')).setParseAction(lambda s, l, t: int(t[0]))
rect_mark = Suppress('R')
comma = Suppress(',')
star = Suppress('*')
semicolon = Suppress(';')
level_str = Combine(star + level)

rect = rect_mark + real + comma + real + comma + real + comma + real + \
       Optional(comma + level_str, default=1) + semicolon + StringEnd()

res = rect.parseString(rtext)
print(res)   # => [0.0, 0.2, 5.7, 0.2, '1']
```

Why does level token not get converted to `int`? Sure, I can convert it in a later processing step, but I'd rather have the input data be consistent.

Comment: It actually does, but `Combine` is converting it back to a string. Also, check out latest `pyparsing.pyparsing_common.real` expression, it is much more efficient than crafting your own with `Combine(Word(nums)) + ...`, and also auto-converts to float.

Comment: @PaulMcG: I see. I was suspecting additional grammar definiton, which follows the conversion, but wasn't able to confirm it on my own. Thank you for your explanation and suggestion.